# istio: VirtualService rewrite to the root url

Tags: kubernetes, routes, istio, envoyproxy

I have an Istio 1.4.6 VirtualService with a match and a url rewrite defined as follows:

```
    match:
    - authority:
        prefix: example.com
      uri:
        prefix: /foo/bar
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: some-service
        port:
          number: 80
```

I would like a rewrite like follows:

Traffic directed to `/foo/bar` or any subpath of that should be rewritten to `/` plus any subpath on `some-service`.

```
i.e.
example.com/foo/bar -> some-service
example.com/foo/bar/subpath -> some-service/subpath
example.com/foo/bar/subpath/anothersubpath -> some-service/subpath/anothersubpath
```

However, when I sysdig the traffic coming into `some-service`, I see that Istio has rewritten the path to:

```
GET //subpath/anothersubpath HTTP/1.1
```

Notice the two slashes in the GET request. In the VirtualService spec `rewrite.uri` field, I can't seem to leave that field empty or add an empty string there. Doing so causes the resource not to validate.

I.e. I can NOT do this:

```
    rewrite:
      uri: ""
```

And can NOT do this

```
    rewrite:
      uri:
```

How can I define a VirtualService rewrite to send traffic to the root of the destination service? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a github [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8076) about this.

The simplest fix is to add whitespace in the `uri` as long as You are not running `.net` core application.

```
    rewrite:
      uri: " "
```

Other workaround can be found [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8076#issuecomment-448738814),

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. Good to know there are several workarounds and an issue for it.

Answer (score 15):

another way of doing this is:

```yaml
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/v2/my-service/"
        - uri:
            exact: "/v2/my-service"
      rewrite:
        uri: "/"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-internal-service
            port:
              number: 6666
```

Comment: Thank you. The only method of listed here which works in my Istio 1.9 :/

Comment: I want to bump this answer. It was the only thing that worked for me. I have a service that will receive calls at `myservice` and `myservice/` and `myservice/some-path` and this solution handles all of them correctly.

Comment: this is definitely the most correct way of handling such behavior